# Copy column information from multiple tables into another sql table and cast false/0 for other column entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, insert

I am currently working in sql server management studio. I have a table lets call TableA. I want to take a column from TableB and input that into TableA, and then insert another column from TableC into TableA dependent upon what was inserted into TableA from TableB. I also need to fill in other columns in TableA with a '0' or 'false' attribute. These are bit columns. I need to know how to use the 'Cast' clause in conjunction with the Insert Into Select clause. Also, can i use a left join for this insert? The code example is from TableA and TableB.

```
INSERT INTO production.dbo.tblPartsOrdered
            (OrderNumber)
SELECT pit.sales.[order].ORDER_NUMBER
FROM   pit.sales.[order]
```

This code seems to work:

```
 Delete from production.dbo.tblPartsOrdered
 INSERT INTO production.dbo.tblPartsOrdered (OrderNumber, ReadyToPush, FabStart,  FabDone, AssyStart, AssyDone, PaintStart, PaintDone, DOStart, DODone, Complete, LineNumber)
 SELECT pit.sales.[order].ORDER_NUMBER, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,      pit.sales.ORD_DTL.LINE_NUMBER FROM pit.sales.[order]
 left join pit.sales.[ORD_DTL] on
 pit.sales.[ORDER].HEADER_ID = pit.sales.ORD_DTL.HEADER_ID
```

Comment: What is it about using a Cast that you need to know in this case?

Comment: I needed to know how to apply the cast to each column, but i think i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
 Delete from production.dbo.tblPartsOrdered
 INSERT INTO production.dbo.tblPartsOrdered (OrderNumber, ReadyToPush, FabStart, FabDone, AssyStart, AssyDone, PaintStart, PaintDone, DOStart, DODone, Complete, LineNumber)
 SELECT pit.sales.[order].ORDER_NUMBER, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, pit.sales.ORD_DTL.LINE_NUMBER FROM pit.sales.[order]
 left join pit.sales.[ORD_DTL] on
 pit.sales.[ORDER].HEADER_ID = pit.sales.ORD_DTL.HEADER_ID
```